# Panda DataFrame: How to partition the dataset by a column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Here is my **data**

```
session_id, event_name
1         , 'click'
2         , 'view'
1         , 'click'
1         , 'view'
2         , 'click'
```

What I am looking for is to :

Analyze all the events from each session_id as an array.

Is this the most efficient way to do this ?

1. Get a list of all session_id
2. Dedup the list
3. iterate through the list of session_id and search by the sessoin_id like
   `df[df['session_id'] == session_id]`

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: `groupby` on `session_id` and then apply on groups like `df.groupby('session_id').apply(youranalysisfunc)`, under the `youranalysisfunc` you'll get access to each session_id's data

Comment: Operations like these ('groupby' in pandas speak) are covered in the [10 minute intro to pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) in the docs. You'll learn a lot of useful techniques if you go through that page.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) `youranalysisfunc`:

```
print df
   session_id event_name
0           1    'click'
1           2     'view'
2           1    'click'
3           1     'view'
4           2    'click'

def youranalysisfunc(x):
    #print x
    #add your code
    x = 'aa' + x
    #add your code
    return x

print df.groupby('session_id')['event_name'].apply(youranalysisfunc)
0    aa'click'
1     aa'view'
2    aa'click'
3     aa'view'
4    aa'click'
dtype: object
```